# Interacting with flash with selenium webdriver Python

Tags: python, selenium, flash, web-scraping

I am trying to build a tool for automatic scraping of information from a website that uses flash along with Oracle BI tool. The information is presented as we select things and flash is used to render the images.

Since I cannot scrap information from the images themselves (to my current knowledge), I found out that right clicking on the image, open a menu with "switch to table" and clicking again on that, opens a page with the data on a table scrapable from the HTML tree. My problem is that clicking on flash object (image), like:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

elem = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '(//embed[@type="application/x-shockwave-flash"])[1]')))

menu=ActionChains(browser).move_to_element_with_offset(elem, 61, 61).click().perform()
```

But then I try to click on the “switch to table” option but I am not being able to do so, since I believe selenium is still clicking on the image below the menu. What I have tried (with different values for offset and using elem and menu elements with no success):

```
ActionChains(browser).move_to_element_with_offset(elem, 75, 75).click()
```

There is any way to do this?
The website is: http://www.adrreports.eu/

Steps to get to the image:

Click language -> search for a report -> pick a letter and then a medicine (new tab appears)-> selecting tab named “Number of individual cases for a selected Reaction”(4th on right top) and then try to get the info from the images on the left

Thank you,

Comment: The link you should try with is `http://www.adrreports.eu/tables/product/a.html` In the link you can see the letter `a` just before `.html` which is the one that can be changed up to `z`. Try to proceed with this clue now.

Comment: Thanks for your input but my problem was a very stupid one since I was on the right tracks but didnt give enough time for the pages to load.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

well this is awkward.

my idea was pretty much usable, even though is not very elegant.
With the offset:

```
menu=ActionChains(browser).move_to_element_with_offset(elem, 61, 61).click().perform()
ActionChains(browser).move_to_element_with_offset(elem, 66, 76).click().perform()
```

I was able to click on the switch table on the flash menu and make the new page appear with the values.

[image: ADR Report flash image]

The main problem was to let the page load, and it seems like it needs quite some time.

```
time.sleep(10)
```

time sleep made the trick!

This method work, but if anyone has a better idea for extracting information from a flash image or file, I would love to hear!

Thank you.